# ActiveAdmin upgrade broke select2-rails : No select2/compat/inputData

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, select2-rails

I have updated my **active_admin** gem to 1.4.3 but as a result it seems it has broken select2-rails gem and the error that I'm getting is:

> Uncaught error: No select2/compat/inputData

```
Ruby: 2.5
Active_admin: 1.4.3
Rails: 4.2.11.1
select2-rails: 3.5.9.1
```

Attaching the screenshot of error: [image]

> active_admin.js.coffee

```
#= require select2
```

> active_admin.css.scss

```
@import "select2";
//= require select2
```

> Gemfile

```
gem 'select2-rails','3.5.9.1'
```

> application.css

```
*= require select2
```

> application.js

```
//=require select2
```

> sample.js

```
$(document).ready ( function() {
    $(".select2_custom_class").select2({
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'something',
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        maximumInputLength: 10,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            results: function(val,page){
            }
        }
  })
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using select2-rails','3.5.9.1' version? It's almost archaic - from July 05, 2014. Can you upgrade a little?